# Pyspark replace NaN with NULL

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark to perform data transformations that I load into Redshift. Redshift does not support NaN values, so I need to replace all occurrences of NaN with NULL.

I tried something like this:

```
some_table = sql('SELECT * FROM some_table')
some_table = some_table.na.fill(None)
```

But I got the following error:

> ValueError: value should be a float, int, long, string, bool or dict

So it seems like `na.fill()` doesn't support None. I specifically need to replace with `NULL`, not some other value, like `0`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally found the answer after Googling around a bit.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, float('nan')), (None, 1.0)], ("a", "b"))
df.show()

+----+---+
|   a|  b|
+----+---+
|   1|NaN|
|null|1.0|
+----+---+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
columns = df.columns
for column in columns:
    df = df.withColumn(column,F.when(F.isnan(F.col(column)),None).otherwise(F.col(column)))

sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "df2")
sql('select * from df2').show()

+----+----+
|   a|   b|
+----+----+
|   1|null|
|null| 1.0|
+----+----+
```

It doesn't use `na.fill()`, but it accomplished the same result, so I'm happy.

Comment: Brilliant. This is a thing I have been searching for quite some time. Thank you.

Comment: What's the advantage of this over [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292987/11301900) ?

Comment: @AMC There probably isn't an advantage of my answer. I wrote my answer about a year before the linked one and didn't realize the newer answer was here until now. I also haven't been able to test the new one myself, so I don't yet feel comfortable marking the newer answer as the accepted answer. Once I'm able to confirm it for myself, which might be awhile because I've moved onto other problems, I'll make the change.

Comment: @user554481 I hadn't noticed that the other answer came so much later! _I also haven't been able to test the new one myself, so I don't yet feel comfortable marking the newer answer as the accepted answer. Once I'm able to confirm it for myself, which might be awhile because I've moved onto other problems, I'll make the change._ Of course, ultimately it's a pretty small thing.

Answer (score 30):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, float('nan')), (None, 1.0)], ("a", "b"))
df.show()

+----+---+        
|   a|  b|
+----+---+
|   1|NaN|
|null|1.0|
+----+---+

df = df.replace(float('nan'), None)
df.show()

+----+----+
|   a|   b|
+----+----+
|   1|null|
|null| 1.0|
+----+----+
```

You can use the `.replace` function to change to `null` values in one line of code.

Comment: This almost worked for me. However, I had to use the following instead: `pd.DataFrame( df ).replace( { float( 'nan' ): None } )`, See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26050.