# How to replace values across all columns in PySpark with non-standard characters in column names?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark job that needs to replace all instances of `NaN` with `None` (aka null). Normally this is pretty easy to accomplish, one you've loaded the dataframe all you have to do is something like this:

```py
df = df.replace(float("nan"), None)
```

However, some of the columns in my dataframe (nearly all of them, in fact) have periods in their names. For instance I have a column named `results.storiesCount`. The mere existence of these columns causes that simple `replace()` call to blow up with this error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "results.storiesCount" among (primaryKey, results.storiesCount, *etc.*);'

How can I accomplish this same effect? I've seen some other answers that mention using `withColumn` and `regexp_replace`, but that doesn't work in this case as `regexp_replace` only lets you replace strings with strings.

Comment: use when, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992713/pyspark-replace-nan-with-null, (you will need to enclose the field names with backticks in isnan() and col() functions)

Comment: Why do you want to replace the NaN with None, by the way?