# Pyspark Getting error while replacing null with 0

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am working on PySpark Python and I have mentioned the code and getting some issue, I am wondering if someone knows about the following issue?

My sample dataset

```
data = [('12er',None), ('4xcf',None), ('6hjk',None), \
      ('45fh',2000),('56gh',2000),('hj45',None)]


columns= ["Id","Amount"]
pivotDF= spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
pivotDF.show(truncate=False)
```

Snippet of original dataset
[image]
I am using fill to replace null with zero

```
pivotDF.na.fill(0).show(n=2)
```

While I am able to do this in sample dataset but in my pspark dataframe
I am getting this error

```
Fail to execute line 1: pivotDF.na.fill(0).show(n=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o244.fill.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'Cancel' is ambiguous, could be: Cancel, Cancel.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.package$AttributeSeq.resolve(package.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveQuoted(LogicalPlan.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolve(Dataset.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.col(Dataset.scala:1269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrameNaFunctions$$fillCol(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions$$anonfun$7.apply(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:502)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions$$anonfun$7.apply(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fillValue(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-3253703896.py", line 473, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2241, in fill
    return self.df.fillna(value=value, subset=subset)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1665, in fillna
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.na().fill(value), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Reference 'Cancel' is ambiguous, could be: Cancel, Cancel.;"
```

My schema
[image]

Comment: you are using `data.na.fill().show()` ? from what i see, `data` variable is a python `list`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, its a dataframe, added my schema at bottom

Comment: so from what it seem, `na.fill` doesn't support `None` value, you refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992713/pyspark-replace-nan-with-null on how to resolve this.

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had roughly 1000 columns and some column names were similar wo case sensitive .

I did

```
spark.sql('set spark.sql.caseSensitive = True')
```

Answer (score 1):

use `df.fillna`

```
data = [('12er',None), ('4xcf',None), ('6hjk',None), \
      ('45fh',2000),('56gh',2000),('hj45',None)]

columns= ["Id","Amount"]
pivotDF= spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)

#fillna on whole dataframe
pivotDF.fillna(0).show(truncate=False)

#fillna on specific columns. { 'col1':0,'col2':10}
pivotDF.fillna( { 'Amount':0} ).show()
```

Out:

```
+----+------+
|  Id|Amount|
+----+------+
|12er|     0|
|4xcf|     0|
|6hjk|     0|
|45fh|  2000|
|56gh|  2000|
|hj45|     0|
+----+------+
```

Comment: You can see it's working with your sample data [here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4404819181006222/3666608711766983/6042668295856651/latest.html).